# Hide a row in SSRS table

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, reporting-services, visibility, business-intelligence

I have a table in my report, that is calculating data from my dataset. I want to hide the rows that calculate results of 0. Here is a screen of my table.

[image]

For the count column, the formula is:

```
=Count(Fields!Age.Value > 90) And Count(Fields!Age.Value < 99)
```

I have tried various expressions both on the cell's property box (visibility expression), as well as the row's visibility. My issue I think is that I don't know how to reference the row/cell with the values.

Comment: Unfortunately, logic (along with CX and QA) isn't one of Microsoft's strong points. Try `=IIF(Count(Fields!Age.Value > 90) And Count(Fields!Age.Value < 99), TRUE, FALSE)`. SSRS doesn't translate logic into TRUE FALSE like it should.

Comment: That is what I used, but it either turns it off or on, depending on the order of True and False. I also tried:    =IIF(Count(Fields!Age.Value > 90) And Count(Fields!Age.Value < 99) = 0, TRUE, FALSE). Is there another way to reference each cell?

Comment: Can you simply put an entry into the where clause of the SQL statement/Query that filters out counts with zero/null as the total?  That should prevent the line from ever being created.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the linked image (I'm assuming due to firewall rules on my end), but based on the description the below formula should work:

```
=Iif(Fields!Age.Value > 90 And Fields!Age.Value < 99, True, False)
```

Place that in the Visibility section of the detail *row group*, rather than attached to an individual textbox.  It will hide the entire row if the age in that detail row meets the criteria. (The Visibility expression sets the Hidden property, which is True for Hidden and False for Not Hidden).

If you're wanting to do this at a higher scope, such as by age bracket, then the formula becomes simpler (and is applied at that group rather than the detail group):

```
=Iif(Count(Fields!Age.Value) = 0, True, False)
```

This is because the group expression itself will take care of filtering the dataset for you, so you can simply see if the group contains any members rather than worrying about what values those members may contain.

If you're *not* grouping by an age-value-related metric, then it becomes more complex:

```
=Iif(Sum(Iif(Fields!Age.Value > 90 And Fields!Age.Value < 99, 1, 0)) = 0,True, False)
```

The Count() function does not evaluate each member item; it simply checks whether it exists.  The Sum() function *does* evaluate each member item, so you can use an Iif() expression to supply the Sum with a 1 or 0 depending on your criteria, and use the result of the Sum to see how many items in the overall set match your filters.